# filter conditions working individually but not together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-hooks

Please check this **filterFunction** & let me know how can i improve it. These filter are working individually but not together

```
const filterFunction = (a) => {
  if (!includeKeyword && !searchVolume && !excludeKeyword && !longtailKeyword){
     return true
  } else if (includeKeyword && !searchVolume){
     return a.text.toLowerCase().includes(includeKeyword.toLocaleLowerCase())
  } else if (!includeKeyword && searchVolume){
     return  a.keyword_idea_metrics.avg_monthly_searches > parseInt(searchVolume)
  } else if (!searchVolume && excludeKeyword){
    return  !a.text.includes(excludeKeyword)
  } else if (!excludeKeyword && longtailKeyword){
    return  a.text.split(" ").length == longtailKeyword
  }  else {
    return  a.text.toLowerCase().includes(includeKeyword.toLocaleLowerCase()) && a.keyword_idea_metrics.avg_monthly_searches > parseInt(searchVolume)  && !a.text.includes(excludeKeyword) && a.text.split(" ").length <= longtailKeyword
  }
}
```

Render Function

```
postRes.filter(filterFunction).map((data, index) => (
```

i really appreciate your help in advance

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: You need to provide more information in your question: what are `includeKeyword`, `searchVolume`, `excludeKeyword` and `longtailKeyword`? Are you trying to filter based on AND or OR combination of these boolean flags?

Answer (score -1):

You are currently passing an uninvoked function with an argument and passing this in properly as the `filter` callback.

I think you could try `postRes.filter((a) => filterFunction(a))...`

Comment: You _are_ supposed to pass an uninvoked function to `filter`, otherwise it will be executed immediately: unless the function is a factory function that returns a function reference.